# XSLT 1.0: how to match nodes according to not completely defined condition?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have this sample input file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <graph>
   <tag name="A_start0"/>
   <tag name="A_end0"/>
   <tag name="A_start1"/> 
   <vertex name="A"/>
   <edge name="AB" />
   <tag name="A_start2"/>
   <tag name="tagA"/>
   <vertex name="C"/>
   <tag name="A_end2"/>
  </graph>
```

I would like to extract all the `tag` node containing `start`word, that are not followed by a node with the same name, but where `start` has been replaced by `end`.

 From my input graph, I would like to obtain:
     `<tag name="A_start1"/>`
The information I have is that there are `tag` elements whose name starts with "A_start" and "A_end", but I have no info about the number following the name.

I suppose I should use `key` to do that, but I do not know how to do this.

Comment: Do you mean you want to extract `A_start1` because it has no `A_end1` following it?

Comment: @michael.hor257k : yes, this is what I want to tell.

Comment: Is the string `A_` before `start` known?

Comment: @michael.hor257k Yes it is known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it can be done with a single XPath expression. Try something like:

```
<xsl:template match="/graph">
    <xsl:for-each select="tag[starts-with(@name, 'A_start')] ">
        <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::tag[@name=concat('A_end', substring-after(current()/@name, 'A_start'))])">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

---

Alternatively, you could go with your idea of using a **key** and do:

```
<xsl:key name="end" match="tag[starts-with(@name, 'A_end')]" use="substring-after(@name, 'A_end')"/>

<xsl:template match="/graph">
    <xsl:copy-of select="tag[starts-with(@name, 'A_start')][not(key('end', substring-after(@name, 'A_start')))]"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I was working on a wrong input! Your solution solved my problem.